# Rotate camera around a point in scene while looking at a different point

Tags: 3d, openscenegraph, coordinate-transformation, perspectivecamera

Here's the problem statement:

I'm trying to setup my camera in `Open scene graph` such that it's looking at a given point but when I rotate it (using a `trackballmanipulator`), it should rotate around a different spin center in space.

So basically the camera is looking at one point but rotating around a different point in scene.

Now from my research so far I gathered that I need to apply some `transformations` to my camera. But I don't quite understand what `transformations` I should be applying.

Can anyone please help me with the math? I'm still trying to learn the CG math.

I have the following information with me:

```
eye (camera position): (eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ)

center (model center): (refX, refY, refZ)

up : (upX, upY, upZ)

Spin center/spin axis: (spinX, spinY, spinZ)
```

Code snippet:

```
osg::Vec3d eye = osg::Vec3d(cameraPos.at(0), cameraPos.at(1), cameraPos.at(2));

osg::Vec3d viewVector = osg::Vec3d(cameraViewDirection.at(0), cameraViewDirection.at(1), cameraViewDirection.at(2));

osg::Vec3d up = osg::Vec3d(cameraUpDirection.at(0), cameraUpDirection.at(1), cameraUpDirection.at(2));

osg::Vec3d modelCenter(eye + viewVector);

osgGA::CameraManipulator *cameraManipulator = view->getCameraManipulator();
osgGA::TrackballManipulator *trackBallManipulator = dynamic_cast<osgGA::TrackballManipulator *>(cameraManipulator);dynamic_cast<osgGA::TrackballManipulator *>(cameraManipulator);

//Transform camera values??

//Apply the viewpoint

trackBallManipulator->setTransformation(transformedEye, transformedCenter, transformedUp);
```

Comment: Can someone please share any ideas on the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a home position for the Trackball manipulator. This is the position and orientation that the manipulator will go back to when pressing space or when you use the `home(double time)` function of the manipulator.

This home position is defined using three vectors; eye, center and up.

- Eye - where in the world the camera is positioned.
- Center - at what point in the world the camera is pointing towards.
- Up - unit vector defining which direction the up-side of the camera should be.

Lets say that we have an object positioned at coordinates `(1.0, 1.0, 0.0)` and we want the trackball manipulator to use this the center of rotation. We want the camera to be positioned a bit back and up, so we define this as the eye vector as `(0.0, 5.0, -10.0)`, ie 5 units up and 10 units back. And finally we want the up direction of the camera to be aligned with the Y-axis, then the Up vector will be `(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)`.

A small code snippet could look like this:

```
// Create a new Trackball manipulator
osg::ref_ptr<osgGA::TrackballManipulator> manipulator = new osgGA::TrackballManipulator;
// Connect the trackball manipulator to the viewer
viewer.setCameraManipulator(manipulator);

// Set the desired home coordinates for the manipulator
osg::Vec3d eye(0.0, 5.0, -10.0);
osg::Vec3d center(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
osg::Vec3d up(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

// Make sure that OSG is not overriding our home position
manipulator->setAutoComputeHomePosition(false);
// Set the desired home position of the Trackball Manipulator
manipulator->setHomePosition(eye, center, up);
// Force the camera to move to the home position
manipulator->home(0.0);

// Start Viewer
while (!viewer.done()) {
    viewer.run();
}
```